# update My Spinner from SQlite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-spinner

**I FOUND A SOLUTION FOR RESTORING MY VALUES, SEE MY NEW VERSION of populateFields()**
Okay so I have been reading through all the Spinner and SQlite posts on here and cannot seem to find a good answer for what I am looking for so I am posting this scenario.
My app has two screens and uses the sqlite database on my device saving a name and weight fields from editTexts as strings like so

```
String eName = name.getText().toString();
String eWeight = weight.getText().toString();// where name and weight are EditTexts
```

and I have two spinners as follows

```
String eReps = spinReps.getSelectedItem().toString();
String eSets = spinSets.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then I call this to add to the database

```
long id = mDbHelper.createExercise(eName, eWeight, eReps, eSets);
```

Here is where my issue is, upon someone selecting to create a new exercise my app crashes because it is trying to populate a spinner incorrectly. Here is what I have currently.

```
private void populateFields(){
  if(mRowId != null){ // where mRowId is the selected row from the list
    Cursor exercise = mDbHelper.fetchExercise();
    name.setText(exercise.getString(exercise.
                 getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
    weight.setText(exercise.getString(exercise.
                 getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_WEIGHT)));
// this is the part that i need help with, I do not know how to restore 
// the current items spinner value for reps and sets from the database.

    spinReps.setSelection(exercise.getString(exercise.
                 getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_REPS)));

    spinSets.setSelection(exercise.getString(exercise.
                 getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_SETS))); 
}
```

I assume I need to use some sort of adapter to restore my list items along with the current value from the database, I am just not sure how.

Can someone please help me with this???

** BELOW IS MY SOLUTION**

I had to move my ArrayAdapters repsAdapter, spinAdapter out of my onCreate()
and then implement this new populateFields()

```
 private void populateFields(){
    if(mRowId != null){
        Cursor exercise = mDbHelper.fetchExercise(mRowId);
       // same as before
        name.setText(exercise.getString(exercise.
                         getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
       // get the string for sReps and sSets from the database
        String sReps = exercise.getString(exercise.
                         getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_REPS));
        String sSets = exercise.getString(exercise.
                         getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_SETS));
       // use the strings to get their position in my adapters
        int r = repsAdapter.getPosition(sReps);
        int s = setsAdapter.getPosition(sSets);
       // set their returned values to the selected spinner Items
        spinReps.setSelection(r);
        spinSets.setSelection(s);
       // same as before
        weight.setText(exercise.getString(exercise.
                         getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_WEIGHT)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set a Spinner to a value, not a position, depends on what adapter you are using.

1. ArrayAdapter, this one is easy:

   ```
   int position = adapter.getPosition(exercise.getString(exercise.
                    getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_REPS)));
   spinReps.setSelection(position);
   ```
2. SimpleCursorAdapter, this one is a little harder:

   ```
   String match = exercise.getString(exercise.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_REPS));

   Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
   cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_REPS);
   while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
       if(cursor.getString(columnIndex).equals(match))
           break;
   }
   spinReps.setSelection(cursor.getPosition());
   ```

If you are using a different type of adapter and can't modify the code above to fit it, let me know. Hope that helps!

Comment: I just read this answer after I figured out how to use my string value to get the position of the string in my adapter and use that returned value to set the position in my spinner, I am not sure but I believe this is what you are explaining to do. Thanks for the effort, I am pumped I found a working solution on my own before I needed help! I will set your answer as a solution to my question because it appears to be the way I have done it.

Comment: Yes, your solution is the same as my first option. Thanks for marking my answer as correct and I'm glad you found the answer as well!